Is it possible to keep a persistent background job on iOS and Android?
I have requirement that I'm unsure about the possibility of. It's an app that has a indefinitely ran background job on iOS and Android that periodically check if the phone is in a geofence zone (Polygon of set coordinates). I've researched this and have discovered some edgecases, such as the behaviour of background jobs if the phone is restarted, app crashed, background job is killed by the OS (It's after all checking GPS coordinates every few seconds).
I have discovered the following package that seems promising: https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation
But I haven't discovered a verified test case that of this working flawlessly (It's business critical that it's flawless and ran at all times once the app is installed). So my question is if this is actually possible? If not what are some alternative ways, an external device that is hooked through e.g BLE?
I've tried:

Tried to identify packages that solved this, found the following but unfortunately crashed the app before I could verify: https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation
Researched edgecases and possibilities with such background geofence functionalities


For Android, a "Foreground Service" plus a Broadcast Receiver listening to boot events should work in most cases.

The short answer is NO.
You can't keep a background task persistent indefinitely.
Android enforced a max 10 minute window for background work since Android 8+.
iOS since...well...since forever.
A workaround for this if you want to "run background tasks indefinitely", you can use Picture in Picture mode in Android/iOS. This allows the app to run in a minimal window in the corner of the device's screen, that allows the app to run in a foreground state.
You can then run all your background tasks/coroutines as normal.
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/picture-in-picture
If you're using react native here's a package you can use:
https://github.com/adkaushik/react-native-pip-android

I had a feeling of this, I had a counter argument given to me that e.g steps counters and the Happn dating app are utilizing background tasks with GPS tracking in a persistent manner. Do you have any ideas on the reality and circumstances are for such claims?
